# Check if a function is L2

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I want to check if a function $f$ defined on $[0,T]$ is a $L_2$ function.

What I know is $f$ is a $L_1$ function. (but $f$ could be not bounded)

So I want to use an inequality like

$$
||\cdot||_{L^{2}} \leq C ||\cdot||_{L^{1}}
$$
where some constant $C$ or function.

Is there the above inequality?

Or how can I prove $f$ is an $L_2$ function and what analytic conditions guarantee $f$ is $L_2$ when $f$ is $L_1$?

Comment: Check Hölder's inequality for $T<\infty$

Comment: If you know the Fourier coefficients $\hat{f}(n)$ of $f \in L^{1}$, then $f \in L^{2}$ iff $\sum_{n}|\hat{f}(n)|^{2} < \infty$.

Comment: In general it is very false that $f \in L^1$ implies $f \in L^2$. Consider e.g. $f(x)= x^{-1/2}$ on $(0,L)$. There are a number of additional assumptions which make this true, but there are too many of these to guess what could be helpful to you. So: What kind of condition are you looking for? Boundedness? Conditions on the Fourier transform? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

Relations between functions from \begin{equation} L_p, L_q \end{equation} called embedding. In general, for 0 ≤ p < q ≤ ∞. \begin{equation} L_q(S, μ) ⊂ L_p(S, μ) \end{equation} when S does not contain sets of arbitrarily large measure, i.e. we have bounded interval and
\begin{equation} L_p(S, μ) ⊂ L_q(S, μ) \end{equation} when S does not contain arbitrarily small sets of non-zero measure, i.e. function does not have non-integrable spikes.
Following relation holds:
\begin{equation} \lVert f \lVert _p \le \lVert f \lVert _q \mu(S)^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}}\end{equation}
There are other similar relations between different functional spaces. For example, search for Sobolev inequality and its generalizations, Nash inequality, etc.;
In general, answer to your question is "yes, but" it requires additional conditions.